# Pointing AWS CloudFront to ECS with Route53 SRV

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-ecs

I was wondering how to point AWS CloudFront to AWS ECS Container using Service Discovery (Route 53 with SRV Record).

ECS is based on Spot EC2 with no Load Balancer.

Comment: Is there any reason it cannot be forwarded to a load balancer? Is the container on an EC2 instance or Fargate?

Comment: It's an EC2 Spot Instance.

Comment: No particular reason on the Load Balancer expect saving on costs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The suggested approach for an architecture running on a container is to have traffic to the container forwarded from a [AWS ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/).

If you're using ECS with service discovery then the record being written is actually written to a private hosted zone which is not accessible outside of the VPC(s) it is attached to.

Furthermore containers are ephemeral, with a risk further increased by using a spot instance that the container could be terminated at any point. If the instance is public facing it would need an [Elastic IP address](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-associate-static-public-ip/) to be associated to it so that it could retain the IP address.

You would want to create an `A record` to this EIP for CloudFront to be able to use it, this A record should have the value of a domain that CloudFront should resolve, and must be in a public hosted zone.

Within your CloudFront distribution the origin value would be set to be the domain name that you setup in the previous step.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable service discovery for Fargate. It uses CloudMap, will automatically create a managed zone and entry inside it. That is the only way to do it without a loadbalancer and hacks. The other way is just to have a lambda function which would update Route53 upon container creation and IP address assignment.

Comment: CloudFront cannot connect to private service discovery namespaces. If you have a domain, then you could setup a public service discovery namespace. But otherwise, AWS forces you to use an application load balancer to connect CloudFront and Fargate ECS.